# RadScheduler mixing appointments

Tags: asp.net, webforms, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-scheduler

I have a RadScheduler from Telerik in my project. There is a RadGrid beneath it on the same page. When I drag an appointment from the grid to the scheduler a different appointment appears on the scheduler.

Here is the RowDrop method of the grid:

```
       protected void AppointmentRadGrid_RowDrop(object sender, GridDragDropEventArgs e)
       {
        GridDataItem dataItem = e.DraggedItems[0];

        var values = new Hashtable();
        dataItem.ExtractValues(values);

        //long id = (long)dataItem.GetDataKeyValue("ID");
        var subject = (string)values["Subject"];
        long saNo = Int64.Parse(values["SANo"].ToString());
        string targetSlotIndex = TargetSlotHiddenField.Value;

        if (targetSlotIndex != string.Empty)
        {
            HandleSchedulerDrop(subject, targetSlotIndex, saNo);
            TargetSlotHiddenField.Value = string.Empty;
        }
        //RadScheduler1.Rebind();
        AppointmentRadGrid.Rebind();

        CheckRadGridPanelVisible();
        }
```

It seems that on this line:

```
         dataItem.ExtractValues(values);
```

wrong values get extracted, which results in wrong appointments being set on the
calendar.

Is this a bug in the RadScheduler or am I doing something wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does copying this demo over in its entirely work for you: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/scheduler/examples/draganddropintegration/defaultcs.aspx?product=grid? Do you create the hash table in the grid ItemCommand event? Does the GetDataKeyValue() method return correct data? If so, you can use only that and add the needed fields to the DataKeyNames property of the table view.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It turned out PopulateScheduler(); in Page_Load was not wrapped in if(!IsPostBack){}

Comment: so, it's OK now? If so, post this as an answer and accept it :) Or I could post that together with the demo link :)

Comment: Yes, it's ok now. Please post an answer and I will accept it since your comment led me to the solution :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Copy the entire code from the original Telerik demo and compare it with yours: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/scheduler/examples/draganddropintegration/defaultcs.aspx?product=grid.
2. Make sure to create the hash table in the grid's ItemCommand event.
3. Use the GetDataKeyValue() method if that returns correct data. You would only need to add the needed fields to the DataKeyNames collection.